# Are Promises Everywhere in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'd like to preface this by saying I come from the Python world, where everything is sequentially structured line by line.

When I test code on Node JS terminal it runs fine because lines of codes are entered sequentially by me. But when I run programs, that's when I see lots of errors that are a result of Node JS's asynchronous nature.

For example: I want to run an mysql call to store an array. Then I want to cycle through the length of that array using a for loop. But when I run the program file, node returns an error because the array is not defined when it tries to execute the for loop (using array.length to stop the loop). I assume this is one area that I should be using a promise.

That being said, is Node JS full of promises everywhere? Or am I missing something big?

Comment: Why is the array not defined before `for` loop begins?

Comment: its not just nodejs, it's javascript in general. it's async by design, callbacks are a cornerstone of the language. if you're have trouble wrapping your head around stuff like this, recommend you start at MDN and learn the basic principles. It's has a lot of functional language paradigms masked as imperative language that confuses people who think they know the language because it's like "java", but don't have a clue about what they are doing. Don't be that person.

Comment: `it's async by design` - no, javascript isn't async, just async functions are async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily promises, but callbacks and promises in general.

Because of the nature of NodeJS, which is single-threaded, it relies heavily on being asynchronous. Otherwise, the calls would block the thread and no other work would be able to execute while dealing with your SQL query.

If you want to deal with async code in a synchronous fashion, check `async/await` or check `yield` (with generators).